App Store Connect - No Builds available to select in Distribution Tab
I'm trying to submit  by clicking "Add For Review" but I get an error because I have to select a build. My build is succeeding but I get 2 warnings :
Failed to export for Ad Hoc Distribution because this team has no iOS devices registered in the Developer Portal. Register an iOS device in the Developer Portal at https://developer.apple.com/account and then try again.
Failed to export for Development Distribution because this team has no iOS devices registered in the Developer Portal. Register an iOS device in the Developer Portal at https://developer.apple.com/account and then try again.
I have added my Mac as s device successfully, so I'm not sure why the warning message tells me "no iOS devices registered in the Developer Portal."
What am I missing here?

mac is not an iOS device. It is a macOS device

I thought you could use Mac as device, you telling me you have to buy an actual IOS device in order to distribute on Apple store??
